# Does rospy logging support "exc_info"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just did some test, and seems that rospy logging ignores `exc_info=True` which is supported by Python loggers.

So when `exc_info` evaluates `True`, python logger also logs the exception info. But I cannot make rospy.logerr() work with this.

Did I miss anything?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303894/does-rospy-logging-support-%22exc_info%22/) by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
What is this a duplicate of?

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-20**:
I forgot to choose the option. It is not a duplicate. It is that the rospy log methods only take `*args`, so it looks obvious it doesn't forward `**kwargs` to python logging. I am going to delete this question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
I've re-opened it for you.

If you'e figured something out, please post an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-20**:
I cannot accept my own answer yet. It requires 10+ points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I didn't notice that rospy log methods only take `*args`. That makes it obvious that they do not support python logger's  `**kwargs` (`exc_info` and `extra`).

PS:

1. `**kwargs` is included in the prototypes of those Python methods. It is just the wiki page that needs to be updated.
2. The support for Python logging's `**kwargs` (`exc_info` and `extra`) will be fixed by:
   https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1289

---

Originally posted by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) with karma: 28 on 2018-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
Is this actually true? I see both `kwargs` as well as `args` [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/89ca9a7bf288b09d033a1ab6966ef8cfe39e1002/clients/rospy/src/rospy/core.py#L190-L203).

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-20**:
But not in this wiki page. http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging
So this is a valid question then. It is a little bit confusing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
The wiki page just doesn't seem to have been updated after [ros/ros_comm#948](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/948) was merged.

Perhaps you can update the wiki or post a comment on the PR asking why the wiki wasn't updated.

**Comment by [yong](https://answers.ros.org/users/37357/yong/) on 2018-09-20**:
Thanks. I will post a comment there, and also point out it probably broke the python logger's `kwargs` handling

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-09-21**:
Actually... this is probably my fault for not updating the documentation back in 2012: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/6